# Transformation formulae for classical theta functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, modular-forms

I am looking for a reference for the transformation formulae
for the classical theta-functions
$$\theta_4(\tau)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^n q^{n^2}$$
and
$$\theta_2(\tau)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty q^{(2n+1)^2/4}$$
under the congruence group $\Gamma_0(4)$.
Here $\tau$ lies in the upper-half plane and $q^x$ denotes
$\exp(2\pi i x\tau)$. More precisely I want the exact automorphy
factors for each $A\in\Gamma_0(4)$ (some eighth root of
unity times $\sqrt{c\tau+d}$). I know these can easily
be deduced from those for the basic theta-function
$$\theta_3(\tau)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty q^{n^2}$$
for which a nice reference for the automorphy factors is Koblitz's *Introduction
to Elliptic Curves and Modular Forms*. However

1. a citation would be useful to me,
2. I want to check my calculation and
3. a reference may give the formulae in a more convenient form than I have.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** I have now found a convenient reference: Rademacher's
*Topics in Analytic Number Theory*.

**FURTHER EDIT** Rademacher actually gives full transformation formula
for the two-variable classical Jacobi theta functions under arbitrary
matrices in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$. From these we can deduce
for $A\in\Gamma_1(4)$ that
$$\frac{\theta_2(A\tau)}{\theta_3(A\tau)}
=i^b\frac{\theta_2(\tau)}{\theta_3(\tau)}$$
and
$$\frac{\theta_4(A\tau)}{\theta_3(A\tau)}
=i^{-c/4}\frac{\theta_4(\tau)}{\theta_3(\tau)}$$
in the usual notation. Once noticed, these relations are easy to prove
from scratch.

Thanks to all who replied to this question.

Comment: Aah curses my first thought was "the Serre-Stark paper in Antwerp VI" (Springer LNM 627) but they only carefully state the factors for theta_3 and you have a reference for that already. They mention Shimura Ann Math 97 (1973) "On modular forms of half integral weight", and Shimura is often very careful about that sort of thing, but I don't know if he'll have what you need.

Comment: Thanks for that. Alas, Shimura also has the formula for $\theta_3$
but not for $\theta_2$ or $\theta_4$. Maybe one can deduce the
formulae from his more general considerations but he doesn't
give the sort of explicit formulae I want. :-(

Answer (score 3):

A classical sourse could be E.T. Whittaker and G.N. Watson, A course of modern analysis, 4th edn. (Cambridge, Cambridge University Press, 1927).

Comment: Alas, although Whittaker and Watson prove the formula
for the substitution $\tau\mapsto-1/\tau$ they do not
give explicit formulae for the general transformation from
$\Gamma_0(4)$.

Comment: But this is really exotic to have the general formula for each of the thetanulls in one book. I have to check whether Yoshida's "Hypergeometric functions--my love" includes this material; the book involves a special "treatment" of $\Gamma_0(4)$ and its modular forms, although it mostly discusses the lambda invariant.

Comment: Thanks in advance, Wadim. I'm not at all familiar with Yoshida's book.

Comment: It depends on why are you looking for the transformation law... I never pay attention to such kind of things, whenever the form of transformation is clear. The major part of my library is packed, so I can hardly be explicit enough. Ken Ono's book discusses this in an explicit form, it could be in Iwaniec's book as well. I am surprised to know that T & M beat W & W at this.

Answer (score 2):

K. Chandrasekharan "elliptic functions" chapter 5  discuss also 2 variales transformation but theta-{2,4} becomes {1,2} in his notation

Comment: Like W and W Chandraskeharan gives only the transformation law for 
$\tau\mapsto−1/\tau$  and not for general elements of $\Gamma_0(4)$.
But they do give a reference to the old treatise of Tannery and Molk.
