# Congruence Subgroups as Open Subgroups of the Modular Group Under the Right Topology

Tags: topological-groups, modular-forms, gr.group-theory, modular-group, nt.number-theory

It occurred to me that a subgroup of the modular group $\Gamma$ is a congruence subgroup iff it contains a subgroup of the form $\Gamma(N)$, while a subgroup of a general topological group is open iff it contains an open subgroup. This suggests making a topology on the modular group $\Gamma$ with the subgroups $\Gamma(N)$ as a basis of open neighborhoods of the origin so that $\Gamma$ becomes a topological group. It would then follow that a subgroup of $\Gamma$ is a congruence subgroup iff it is open.

Furthermore, for any $\gamma \in \Gamma$ not equal to the identity, there exists $N$ such that $\gamma \notin \Gamma(N)$, so this topology is Hausdorff, even totally disconnected.

I was inspired in part by [this thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20929/distinguishing-congruence-subgroups-of-the-modular-group) and looked at [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1996-124-05/S0002-9939-96-03496-X/S0002-9939-96-03496-X.pdf) but could not find anything about this idea.

Has anyone considered this topology? Does it provide insight into the problem of determining whether a group is a congruence subgroup?

Comment: My first reaction is that this is related to the adelic topology on $GL_2$, although exactly how would require some further thought on my part.  Probably someone else here will be able to follow up on this before I get back to it...

Comment: The kernel of the map from the profinite completion of $\Gamma$ to the completion with respect to the congruence topology is called the $\textit{congruence kernel}$ and has been studied in connection with the congruence subgroup problem.

Comment: @Pete: So does your comment hold up that it is somehow related to the adelic topology on $GL_2$?

Comment: @Pete: Over a year later, having learned more, I think you're basically right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To expand Henry Wilton's concise answer, the Congruence Subgroup Problem has a distinguished history including important work by Serre and a number of others (exploiting effectively the congruence topology).    See for example:
[MR0272790](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0272790) (42 #7671) 14.50,
Serre, Jean-Pierre,
Le problème des groupes de congruence pour SL2. (French)
Ann. of Math. (2) 92 1970 489–527.

This sort of topology on a group originates earlier, but the application here is highly original.

ADDED: Like many other journal articles, the one mentioned here by Serre is available in PDF format but only through JSTOR (or other library resource).   There is a lot of literature, including my 1980 Springer Lecture Notes 789 *Arithmetic Groups* which cover some of the background as well as an expository account of Matsumoto's thesis.

Answer (score 10):

It's called the congruence topology, and is (obviously) always at least as coarse as the profinite topology.  If your group has the Congruence Subgroup Property (the modular group doesn't, but $SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ does for $n>2$) then it's the same as the profinite topology.

A google search found, for instance, [Section 7.3](http://books.google.com/books?id=1D6crOEoRFEC&pg=PA200&lpg=PA200&dq=congruence+topology&source=bl&ots=d-mel58Uo0&sig=Lxim14zcfsKZdMxgO2gU9otjPGY&hl=en&ei=TZx2TN3sGIW-sQPjktCgDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=11&ved=0CFEQ6AEwCg#v=onepage&q=congruence%2520topology&f=false) of *Algebraic theory of the Bianchi groups* by Benjamin Fine.

Comment: Modulus Margulis rigidity, this is the same answer as mine. For $SL(2)$ you have to take the profinite completion with respect to a special sequence of subgroups.

Answer (score 4):

You can take the profinite completion $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}} = \prod_p \mathbb{Z}_p$ of $\mathbb{Z}$, then open subgroups of $G( \widehat{\mathbb{Z}})$ correspond to congruence subgroups in $G(\mathbb{Z})$.

The identification is easy:

$$ \Gamma \; congruence \leftrightarrow K \; open$$

"$\rightarrow$": Assume you have a congruence subgroup $\Gamma \subset \Gamma(N)$, then we can consider
$$ \Gamma / \Gamma(N) \subset SL_2(\mathbb{Z} / N) = \prod\limits_{p^k || N} SL_2(\mathbb{Z} / p^k ).$$
Define $K = K(\Gamma)$ as the pullback of $\Gamma / \Gamma(N)$ along the surjection
$$p: \prod\limits_{p} SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p) \rightarrow \prod\limits_{p^k || N} SL_2(\mathbb{Z} / p^k )$$

"$\leftarrow$": Pick $\Gamma = K \cap SL_2(\mathbb{Q})$, where $SL_2( \mathbb{Q})$ is diagonal subgroup $\prod\limits_p SL_2(\mathbb{Q}_{p})$.

Answer (score 4):

It's worth mentioning that there is a general definition of the "congruence subgroup topology" on the automorphism group of a profinite group $\widehat{A}$: namely, the open subgroups of $\text{Aut}(\widehat{A})$ under this topology are generated (as a topology) by the subgroups
$$\Gamma[K]: = \ker(\text{Aut}(\widehat{A})\rightarrow\text{Aut}(\widehat{A}/K))$$
as $K$ varies over finite index characteristic subgroups of $\widehat{A}$. You can find this for example in Ribes/Zalesskii's book *Profinite Groups* $(\S4.4)$. In the same way we also obtain a "congruence subgroup topology" on $\text{Out}(\widehat{A})$.

For a general abstract discrete group $G$, for every abstract group $A$ and a homomorphism $\phi : G\rightarrow\text{Aut}(A)$ (or $\text{Out}(A)$), one obtains the notion of "congruence subgroups" on $G$ (relative to $\phi$), which are by definition those subgroups which contain a preimage of some $\Gamma[K]$ under the map

$$G\stackrel{\phi}{\longrightarrow}\text{Aut}(A)\subset\text{Aut}(\widehat{A}),$$
where the hat denotes profinite completion.

For the modular group $G := \text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, one can naturally take $A = \mathbb{Z}^2$, and consider the natural homomorphism 
$$\phi : \text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}^2)$$
 Then, $\text{Aut}(\widehat{\mathbb{Z}^2}) = \text{GL}_2(\widehat{\mathbb{Z}})$, the finite index characteristic subgroups of $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}^2$ are $K_n := n\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}\times n\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$, and the preimage of $\Gamma(K_n)$ in $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is just the classical principal congruence subgroup $\Gamma(n)$.

However, for $G = \text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, there is another natural choice for $\phi$, given by noting that if $F_2$ denotes the free group of rank 2, then $\text{Out}(F_2)\cong\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$. From this, one obtains a natural map
$$\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})\stackrel{\phi'}{\longrightarrow}\text{Out}(F_2)\subset\text{Out}(\widehat{F_2})$$
The preimages of $\Gamma[K]$ as $K$ varies over finite index characteristic subgroups of $\widehat{F_2}$ then generate the congruence subgroups (relative to $\phi'$) in the sense described above.

The cool thing is that while $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ doesn't have the congruence subgroup property relative to $\phi$, it does relative to $\phi'$. In particular, there are finite index subgroups of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ which are congruence relative to $\phi'$, but not congruence in the usual sense (ie relative to $\phi$). There is a paper of [Bux-Ershov-Rapinchuk](https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.0304) which has a nice description of this phenomenon, though the result they prove is originally due to Asada.

In fact, the notion of congruence relative to $\phi$ gives rise to the usual moduli interpretations of "congruence" modular curves, whereas the more general notion of congruence relative to $\phi'$ gives rise to the moduli interpretations for "noncongruence" modular curves.

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph, is that basically how your thesis works? Do you then think of $F_2$ as the fundamental group of $\mathbb{P}^1 \setminus \{0,1,\infty\}$?

Comment: @DavidCorwin Not quite, you just think of $F_2$ as the fundamental group of a punctured elliptic curve. The relation between $\mathbb{P}^1 - \{0,1,\infty\}$ and a punctured elliptic curve is somewhat subtle, and is essentially what is exploited in Asada's proof of the congruence subgroup property for $Aut(F_2)$. One relation between the two (which is not really exploited by Asada) is that the cusps of noncongruence modular curves correspond to certain types of dessins d'enfant.